# Rendering same component (with synced data) twice on same page

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I've read a lot of documentation but I can't get the following use case to work:

I've got a component 'product-filter'. This component contains the child component 'product-filter-option' which renders a individual filter option (checkbox with label)

The json data for a product-filter instance looks like:

```
"name": "category",
  "title": "Category",
  "options": [
    {
      "value": "value",
      "label": "Label 1",
      "active": true,
      "amount": 8
    },
    {
      "value": "value2",
      "label": "Label 2",
      "amount": 15
    },
    etc.
  ]
```

I've got multiple instances of product-filter (and a lot of product-filter-option instances) on my page. So far so good.
Now I'd like to render one of my filters (eg. the given Category filter) multiple times on my page (sort of current 'highlighted' filter, which can change during user interaction).

So I've tried to fix this with the following template code:

```
<filter-component v-if="activefilter"
                                  :name="activefilter.name"
                                  :type="activefilter.type"
                                  :title="activefilter.title"
                                  :tooltip="activefilter.tooltip"
                                  :configuration="activefilter.configuration"
                                  :options="activefilter.options">
        </filter-component>
```

So this filter now shows up 2 times on my page (only when the activefilter property in the vue app is set). **But** as you might guess when changing an option in this 'cloned' filter the original filter doesn't change, because the data is not synced between these 'clones'.
How can I fix this with Vue?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `:options.sync="activefilter.options"` ? I probably don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Is there any way you could distill it down to a simple snippet that demonstrates the issue?

Comment: @RoyJ this was indeed part of the fix. I tried this earlier, but I missed another sync, see my anwser below. Thanks for your insight!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@roy-j, thanks for your comment about sync. I already tried that by setting:

```
<filter-component v-if="activefilter"
                                      :name="activefilter.name"
                                      :type="activefilter.type"
                                      :title="activefilter.title"
                                      :tooltip="activefilter.tooltip"
                                      :configuration="activefilter.configuration"
                                      :options.sync="activefilter.options">
            </filter-component>
```

This didn't work. **But** You got got me thinking, the options sync was not the issue, the sync of the 'checked' state was the issue.
It worked by changing :checked="option.active" to :checked.sync="option.acitve" to the child component: 'filter-option-component'!

Thanks!!